# Loading large javascript in script tag leads to error "Out of memory" in chrome 105 version

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, out-of-memory, chromium, v8

We have developed an offline Application where we store json in Javascript file inside a variable, and only load single required javascript when clicked on button(We dont load all at once). with the help of javascript.

```
       var view ;
       var viewID;
       view = file;  
       viewID = view.split("v")[1];
       viewIds.push(viewID);
            // DOM: Create the script element
       var jsElm = document.createElement("script");
            // set the type attribute
        jsElm.type = "application/javascript";
        jsElm.id = file;
            // make the script element load file
        jsElm.src = "viewData/"+viewID+".js";
            // finally insert the element to the body element in order to load the script
        document.body.appendChild(jsElm);
         
        
        //  $('#loading').show();
     try {
        jsElm.onload = function () {
             defaultViewData(view);
         
         jsElm.onerror = function () {
          alert('something Went wrong');
         }
        }   
     } catch (error) {
         alert(error);
     }
```

we also dont load the same javascript again if already loaded.

two of the script is really big that is around 500MB, when it starts its load the RAM memory goes upto 8GB and then when it done loading it get backs to normal that is 700MB.

if switching between while memory is comming down it again utilises RAM additionally to load another script and SNAPs stating "Out of Memory".

This was working very normal in chrome 103 and 104, after updating to 105 this started running into error not only in chrome but also in all the chromium based browsers like now Edge, I guess there is some thing to notice in v8 engine update, which is changed.

or is there any other way to get data in the webApp without server, Currently we are getting data inside with help of javascript which is big ,

Also like to know that for 500 MB , 8 GB is utilsed what happens there?

Note : Everything is absolutly normal in firefox browser still.

In our processing javascript we have tested using timeout functions to wait and HeapSize to get normal but randomly it gets snaps saying "Out of Memory".

Comment: `for 500 MB , 8 GB is utilsed what happens there?` Chrome is hot garbage - is it possible to change the javascript to json and load it using fetch instead - the fact that you say `we store json in Javascript file` suggests that it is possible ... if it's **actually** real JSON of course - i.e. only strings, numbers, arrays, booleans, nulls and simple objects - e.g. no type that isn't valid JSON

Comment: fetch again works with server , it doesnot allow us to read the filr from local computer for security reasons.

Comment: ohh, so this page is loaded using `file://` rather than `http://` or `https://` - not sure it would've made any difference - would've been interesting to find out though

Comment: I think this falls into the "[Now, you may think that you have asked a reasonable, answerable question, but you really haven't](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/943435)" category.

Comment: @yogi what exactly you dont understand about the question?, it is not a research this some thing that most of the developer on interenet looking for and trying to understand that Loading of 500MB js in html page utilizes 8GB of RAM, If you know please answer it it would be helpful for someone instead of just commenting that the question is not understood.

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes page is loading using file://, This was working well in chrome 104 version , we are using this since last 4 years.

Comment: Chrome does tend to randomly break things - who knows, next version may work again (try Chrome Canary)

Answer (score 1):

> This was working very normal in chrome 103 and 104, after updating to 105 this started running into error

To report a Chrome bug, go to [crbug.com/new](https://crbug.com/new). Be sure to include a repro case -- the description you've given here is very likely not enough for anyone to figure out what the problem is. (For example: there are many limits for various resources (such as: total virtual memory reserved, actual memory allocated, different buckets for different kinds of allocations, maximum size of an individual object or string, ...), and it's not obvious which one you're running into.)

> for 500 MB , 8 GB is utilsed what happens there?

The size of a JSON string is a very unreliable indicator for the memory consumption of the objects/data encoded in that string. For example:

- The number `1` takes 1 byte in a JSON string and 4 bytes on the heap;  `1012023034` takes 10 bytes of JSON and also 4 bytes on the heap.
- The number `.5` takes 2 bytes of JSON and 12 bytes on the heap; `3.141592653589793` takes 17 bytes of JSON and also 12 bytes on the heap.
- The string `"xy"` takes 2 bytes of JSON and 16 bytes on the heap.
- For objects it's hard to give a concrete number because they can share some metadata (such as the hidden class, and the names of their properties) if several objects of the same/similar shape exist; as a lower bound a single-property object like `{"a":1}` (7 bytes of JSON data) will never use less than 16 bytes on the heap under ideal conditions, and may need a lot more than that if it's the only object of its shape.
- An array like `[1]` (3 bytes of JSON) needs at least 28 bytes on the heap.

Aside from the size of objects on the heap, the parser also needs some temporary memory. In fact, the heap currently has a hard limit at 4GB (due to pointer compression), so if you see the renderer taking 8GB total memory, then at least half of that is guaranteed to be off-heap.

> We dont load all at once

Going further in that direction is probably the best path forward: 500 MB of JSON is a lot; maybe there's room for loading only small chunks of that as required? If someone wants to load your site on a laptop/tablet/phone with only 2 GB of memory, then any limit-raising in Chrome won't help, you'll actually have to make the app itself leaner.

Comment: Explaination looks great and will noted for my knowledge too thanks, One thing which we are wondering that this was handled in the older versions , I agree that 500MB of json data is too big to read in local,

Comment: One more thing wanted to share here, this goes out of memory while appending html data to page.